# How can I obtain the name of the logged user inside a form of a Django App and use the results as input of a form field?

Tags: django, django-forms, django-admin

I would like to obtain the name of the logged user inside a form of a Django App and use the results as input of a form field.

How can I do that? What should I do in my code?

Here is my code

Views.py

```
form = ProductForm()
```

Admin.py

```
class AccessLevelInline(admin.StackedInline):
    model = AccessLevel
    can_delete = False
    verbose_name_plural = 'accesslevel'

# Define a new User admin
class UserAdmin(BaseUserAdmin):
    inlines = (AccessLevelInline, )

# Re-register UserAdmin
admin.site.unregister(User)
admin.site.register(User, UserAdmin)
```

Form.py

```
user_name = HOW DO I ACCESS THE USER NAME HERE?
u = User.objects.get(username=user_name).accesslevel.prod.split(',')
v=(('---------','---------'),)
for l in u:
    v=v+((l.lstrip(),l.lstrip()),)

class ProductForm(forms.Form):
    model = Manufact    
    Prod = forms.ChoiceField(choices=v)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Expanding off of [Stepan's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47818198/obtain-the-name-of-the-logged-user-inside-a-form-of-a-django-app-and-use-the-res/47818780#47818780).

In `views.py`:

```
form=ProductFrom(request.user)
```

In `forms.py`:

```
# Declare __init__ function

def __init__(self, user_name):
    self.u = User.objects.get(username=user_name).accesslevel.prod.split(',')
    # DO the rest that you need here.
```

Answer (score 0):

In your view you have access to the `request` object which has the the current user on it. You can get it like this: `request.user`. So you can pass that to your form when you initialize it so you have access to when you need it.

`form=ProductForm(request.user)`

Comment: I did the following: in views form=ProductForm(request.user) and in forms user_name = request.user.username. But I am having the following error: NameError: name 'request' is not defined